# How to darken the div surrounding an alert like a modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to show `alert` to the user and I want it to be pretty. So I use *Bootstrap's alert class*, and show to user `div` like this:

```
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
    Some text
</div>
```

This code just shows a `div`. What I want is to darken everything, except this `div` (like modals in Bootstrap do). How can I do this?

Comment: Use a modal with an alert inside it

Comment: @user1672694 I tryed, but modal class trying to wrap my alert. Even if I set it's heading, body and footer sizes to 0

Comment: @Fkids , yes, it is. But try to find the answer there. All the answers to this question are links and they are 404

Comment: I would say not a duplicate as this is using Bootstrap

Comment: use this http://bootboxjs.com/

Comment: @user1672694 , moreover, there are no answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opens the modal, only shows the alert.

http://jsfiddle.net/phLg32eL/1

HTML:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Open alert
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                Some text
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.modal-content {
    height:52px
}
```

Comment: Oh, thanks you. When I tryed to do it I forgot to set alert's div margin to 0. So, because of it, it has been wrappend by modal